# Changing Stroke Cap Angle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, stroke

I'm trying to animate a logo I made using trim path. I'm having trouble with the circle. I'm trying to recreate the logo's filled circle outline with a single stroke path. The issue is that the end caps are not at the same angle as the circle due to the cut out. The normal circle is like the letter 'C' and is cut at 45 degrees with some buffer due to the width of the cut. When I make a stroke and cut it to the same position the cap of the stroke wants to lay at a default angle and not the one like the logo. Here is an example:

[image: Stroke Example]

How can I made it so the cap's angle is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the stroke and adjust.

In some cases, you may be able to use arrowheads or brushes. 
See here: [Custom stroke caps in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator)

You **can't** alter the (perpendicular) angle of the default stroke caps.

Comment: mmm interesting, I'll give it a shot. The purpose is to transfer it over to adobe after effects. Do you know if you can have custom stroke caps in that as well?

Comment: Sorry I'm not an After Effects user. I don't have enough knowledge to answer regarding AE.