# How to cut off a piece at the end of my stoke line? (Adobe Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: This is what I thought of]

It's important that it's done with stroke so I can animate with trim paths later in After Effects. I found the rounded edges but I can't seem to find this type of stroke.

Comment: Do you mean you want the [*angled* end cap](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom stroke caps in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator)

Comment: I can't seem to work it out, if anyone could give me a detailed step by step guide for this I would be really thankful. Cheers!