# Convert Shape Layer to Stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hey, I know this is a very old question, but my question is a bit different. I have a problem converting this layer to stroke. I attached the image in the post. When I try to convert a shape to stroke this is the result I get. In the image, on the left, the 'V' has a flat, horizontal end, but when I convert it into a stroke, the shape end shifts to a diagonal. I searched everywhere to fix this thing, but couldn't find any. Kindly help me out here

Comment: No real fix, exists thats why we dont keep everything stroked. Anyway you dont say why you need to make it a stroke there are atleast 5 different usecases where youd want to do this and all of them have different solutions. Care to expand a bit as it sounds like a x/y question to me

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Why do you want the V to be constructed using a stroke rather than a filled path?  What are you going to use this for?  Is there some reason you haven't revealed that means you can't convert the stroke to paths, and then edit the paths to create the correct angle? As @joojaa says, as currently written, your question reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/138576/edit) to add more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The **only** way to alter the end cap of strokes in Illustrator is via brushes or arrowheads. Otherwise, stroke caps are **always** perpendicular to the stroke. It is simply how Illustrator works. You can't alter the perpendicular cap with any simple setting adjustment.

**See here for some possible help with end caps:** [Custom stroke caps in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator)

However, in this particular case, it may require you to determine the *angle* at which you want the cap, then create a custom cap at that *specific* angle.

Comment: Not just how illustrator works. How strokes work, strokes work like this in EPS, PDF and SVG specifications. And this is also why pathfinder booleans expand strokes. OP might want to use a clipping mask.