# Custom arrowhead not aligning to the bottom of the stroke when scaled

Tags: adobe-illustrator, arrow

Is it possible to align the arrowhead to the width of the stroke, rather than the vector point of the stroke when scaling the arrowhead? Like this example in use:

[image: Arrowheads in use display]

1. The first being the original arrowhead, at 100% scale.
2. The second one is scaled at 60%. It aligns to the stroke vector point.
3. The third one is what I'm wondering if it's possible, scaled at 60%. It aligns to the bottom of the stroke.

I already tried with this configuration when creating the arrowhead symbol, but it doesn't seems to be meant for that. It didn't work.

I'm using Illustrator 2019

[image: Settings preview]

Comment: Not sure where the *symbol* comes into play. You don't need symbols to create custom arrowheads. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@surbhivdesigner/customized-arrowhead-in-illustrator-327bc0c3009b

Answer (score 0):

A workaround only:

Use a custom stroke which has its centerline in the visible bottom. You get it by using an art brush. The next image shows one possible brush shape:

[image]

It has 2 equally high rectangles. The upper one has no stroke and brown fill. The bottom rectangle has no fill nor stroke. Select both of them at the same time and drag to the brushes panel. Select option an "art brush".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is merely an alignment issue with the path and the arrowhead. It's difficult to say for certain without seeing things in **Outline Mode**.

[image]

##### It is also important to note that *proper* scaling for some arrowheads only occurs with changes to the stroke weight.

If one uses the arrowhead scale %, some arrowheads will lose alignment. This is *especially* true for off center arrowheads. Even the Adobe included off-center arrowheads won't scale properly if one uses the arrowhead %. They only scale properly when the stroke weight changes. **Really, the arrowhead % on the Stroke Panel only works well with *centered* arrowheads.**

Note how the arrowhead alignment changes on this Adobe brush ....

[image]

Ultimately, if you want your pointed, off-center, arrowhead to be 40% smaller, you need to **create it** 40% smaller and **not** rely on the arrow % in the Stroke Panel. This *may* mean you need multiple sizes for your arrowhead.

Or... you can use an **Art Brush** in some cases.

[image]

Art Brushes ensure alignment is always correct, but they do eliminate the ability to scale only the "head".