# Illustrator: can I change the edge of a stroke to give the shape i wanted to it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, alignment, font-design, borders

So im currently creating a font but i cant figure out how to allign the edge of my stroke with my guidline. As you can see in the image, I'm creating open path so i can change the width later (for example create bold font or to increase their size). I have to create this for all my letters so if it can be a bit more general to apply it to other letters that maybe will have the same problem.

Could you help me with this, or let me know a better way to create these graphics to change width later?

Thanks for all people that will help with this problem.[image: Edge I need to change][image: Path of my strokes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well no. But you can circumvent this:

What i do however is just draw a transparent object over the end and use it as a knockout over the text. This gets erased when you run the transparency flattener before exporting the curves to a font generator. So now you can adjust curve widths.

[image]

**Image 1**: Animated line thickness

[image]

**Image 2**: Showing knockout zones and lines

Answer (score 1):

Generally the fonts contain strokeless, but filled closed areas. Fonts which are only open lines and curves with no filled areas are special products for machine engraving and common graphic software do not understand them. An example:

This cannot be in a font, because it contains only a few open lines:

[image]

But this is a closed strokeless area, actually a compound path because it has a hole. One could well use it in a font:

[image]

It's made by expanding the strokes and making them one by applying pathfinder unite. The ends of the legs of the A can be edited to have any forms, there are no stroke ending limitations. A simple editing example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

**Stroke** caps are **always** one of three options:

- rounded
- angled, perpendicular to the stroke, stopping at the final anchor
- or angled, perpendicular to the stroke, extending past the final anchor.

It is *not possible* to alter the angle of a stroke's end cap. 
It will **always** be perpendicular to the stroke....

.... as a *stroke*....

You *can*...

- Expand the stroke to a shape (via `Object > Expand`) and adjust the resulting shape
- In some instances, use [custom stroke caps or brushes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/custom-stroke-caps-in-illustrator/36205#36205) 
  <sup>(Although, for multiple angles this may get rather laborious.)</sup>